# Voltage to current circuit simulation problem

Tags: current, control

I want to control current through of R8 resistor adjusting VS1 voltage. VS1 increased from 0 to 5V, but AM1 and VF1 don't increase or change. 
Is there anybody give an idea about the mistake?
[image]

After comments
1)R4 reduced to 5Kohm
2)Drain and source swapped
Maybe better now. But it saturated. 
[image]

Comment: What is your loop gain?

Comment: This circuit from an example report, it says about 0.25 A/V.

Comment: T3 is miswired, drain and source have to be swapped. Then you will probably have loop stability issues, but as a starter, fix wiring first

Comment: What's the voltage range for your controlling input? What's the current compliance for your controlling input voltage? What purpose does \$R_6\$ and \$R_7\$ serve here? What is the mapping of controlling input voltage to resulting current through \$R_8\$?

Comment: Input control range:0 to 5V, current flow desired 0 to 1Ampere. R6 and R7 just feedback to controller, for measurement real current.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your gate is already saturated.

Try reduce R4.

You can't control the current accurately through R8 with this circuit, MOSFET have big temperature dependency and your voltage will vary as the MOSFET heats up.

Also the gate threshold will vary from one mos to another. If you wan't any sort of stable current regulation you need some sort of feedback circuit.

You need to have some sort of feedback regulation.

[Check this circuit](http://www.pcbheaven.com/userpages/LED_driving_and_controlling_methods/?topic=worklog&p=3) that allows to control the current, can be a LED or Resistor.